# Internal links being changed by mod_pagespeed

Tags: javascript, mod-pagespeed

I noticed that when using mod_pagespeed on my site it updates my internal links.

When I am on `/` then my navigation looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="foo/bar"></a></li>
    <li><a href="example"></a></li>
</ul>
```

But when I am on `/foo` the same navigation looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="bar"></a></li>
    <li><a href="/example"></a></li>
</ul>
```

And when I am on `/example` it looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/foo/bar"></a></li>
    <li><a href="example"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to stop this behaviour as it's breaking some JS that relies on the `href` attribute of each link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable this feature by adding

```
ModPagespeedDisableFilters trim_urls
```

to your `pagespeed.conf` file. See https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/filter-trim-urls for more details.